# Printing 3 decimal numbers for a double

Tags: java

I am supposed to find the average of a bunch of given numbers after adding all of them up then dividing by the number of numbers given to me and the average must have 3 decimal numbers so for instead of 45.0 it would be 45.000 and mine works but only if the last number is not 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Average
{
   private String line;
   private double average, sum, count;

   public Average()
   {
     setLine("");
   }

   public Average(String s)
   {
     setLine(s);
   }

 public void setLine(String s)
 {
   line = s;
   sum = 0.0;
   count = 0.0;
   average = 0.0;
 }

 public double getCount()
 {
  int num = 0;
  while(num<line.length())
  {
    if(line.charAt(num) == 32)
    {
      count ++;
      num ++;
    }
    else
      num ++;
  }
  count ++;
  return count;
 }

 public double getSum()
 {
  Scanner bobby = new Scanner(line);
  while(bobby.hasNextInt())
    sum = sum + bobby.nextInt();
  return sum;
 }

 public double getAverage()
 {
  average = getSum()/getCount();
  average = average*1000;
  if(average%10>4)
  {
  average = Math.floor(average);
  average ++;
  average = average/1000.0;
  }
  else
  {
  average = Math.floor(average);
  average = average/1000.0;
  }
  return average;
  }

 public String getLine()
 {
  return line;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  return "";
 }
}
```

This is my runner file

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class AverageRunner
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
     String s = "9 10 5 20";
     Average bob = new Average(s);
     System.out.println("Find the average of the following numbers :: "+s);
     System.out.println("Average = " + " " + bob.getAverage());
     System.out.println();

     s = "11 22 33 44 55 66 77";
     Average bob1 = new Average(s);
     System.out.println("Find the average of the following numbers :: "+s);
     System.out.println("Average = " + " " + bob1.getAverage());
     System.out.println();

     s = "48 52 29 100 50 29";
     Average bob2 = new Average(s);
     System.out.println("Find the average of the following numbers :: "+s);
     System.out.println("Average = " + " " + bob2.getAverage());
     System.out.println();

     s = "0";
     Average bob3 = new Average(s);
     System.out.println("Find the average of the following numbers :: "+s);
     System.out.println("Average = " + " " + bob3.getAverage());
     System.out.println();

     s = "100 90 95 98 100 97";
     Average bob4 = new Average(s);
     System.out.println("Find the average of the following numbers :: "+s);
     System.out.println("Average = " + " " + bob4.getAverage());
 }
}
```

Comment: Only, you know, three instead of two...

Comment: What exactly is the question? What does your code do and what do you want it to do? What is left? Where you have difficulties doing it yourself? What confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000"); 
System.out.println("Nummber: " + df.format(1.2345));
```

Comment: How would i write it though, because im saying bob.getAverage so would i just do bob.df.format.getAverage?

Comment: Just pass bob.getAverage() to df#format(String)